# python3 images in imported modules

Tags: python, image, tkinter, module

I am writing a program in Python 3.10 on a W11 machine to do things with a large collection of images.  The images are divided into categories. Each category is treated slightly differently and there is a front end menu to select the category and import the relevant module.   Each module is written as a stand alone .py file.  My problem is that although the modules run well as stand alone files, when imported I get an error "tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist".  Two bits of hopefully minimum reproducible examples are included; Universal Viewer test.py which is the menu script and Art_Viewer_test which is imported as a module. Pointers to the error would be appreciated.

MENU CODE
'''

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
root = Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(bg="black")
def q_key_pressed(event):                                                            
    if root.attributes("-fullscreen")==False: 
        root.attributes("-fullscreen", True) 
    else:
        root.attributes("-fullscreen", False) 
    sys.exit()
def act_on_selection(x):
    if x==1:
        import Art_Viewer_test
opening_menu_frame=Frame(root,bg="black",relief='flat',bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
text_for_heading='\n\n\n\n\n\n\nIMAGE VIEWER\n\n\n'
heading=Label(opening_menu_frame,bg='black',fg='lightgray',font= 
             ("Arial","16"),text=text_for_heading,bd=0)
heading.pack()
art = Button(opening_menu_frame,pady=15,borderwidth=0,text="Art Images",font= 
                   ("Arial","16"),bg='black',fg='white',command=lambda: 
act_on_selection(1))
art.pack()
inst_text='\n\n\n\n\n\n\nClick one of the catagories or Q to exit the program'
instruction=Button(opening_menu_frame,borderwidth=0,text=inst_text,font= 
                    ("Arial","16"),bg='black',fg='white')
instruction.pack()
opening_menu_frame.pack()                      
root.bind("q",q_key_pressed) and root.bind("Q",q_key_pressed)
root.mainloop()'''
```

MODULE CODE

'''

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root = Tk()
def right_key_pressed():
    #do stuff
    pass
control_frame=Frame(root,bg="lavender",relief='flat', borderwidth=40)
control_frame.pack() 
image=Image.open("icons/next.gif")
nexticon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
nextimageclick=Button(control_frame,image=nexticon, text 
                       ="next",compound="bottom",command=right_key_pressed)
nextimageclick.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: You are using two instances of `Tk()` in your code and the `PhotoImage` does not know which widget you want it to belong to. _Always_ use `Toplevel()` to make child windows

Comment: got it - thanks